# jQuery UI sortable where numbers don't move

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery UI for a ranked ballot and you can see an example [here](http://opal.openstv.org/vote?ekey=agNzdHZyEAsSCEVsZWN0aW9uGLnnDww).

I'd like to change it so that when the voter drags the candidate names, the names move but the numbers next to them don't.

I know I could do this by hiding the list numbers and adding a separate, stationary list of numbers next to the sortable, but I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Any ideas for an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: The problem is the number doesn't change while dragging?

Comment: No, the problem is that I don't want the numbers to move at all.  I'd like to have only the boxes next to them move.

Comment: It seems kind of impossible without breaking it to two separate list

Comment: @Nayish, might be impossible, but I was hoping not. :)

Comment: Yah, unless you're willing to do the two separate lists, or create your own drag/drop tools, you're kinda stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a pretty easy way to accomplish this.  Suppose this is the list:

```
<div id="ballot">
<ol id="sortable">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Then the following javascript will add a number to the left of each list item:

```
window.onload = function(){
  $("#sortable li").each(function(n) {
    var pos = $(this).position();
    var number = document.createElement('p');
    number.innerHTML = (n+1) + ".";
    $(number).css("position", "absolute");
    $("#ballot").append(number);
    $(number).position({
      my: "center",
      at: "left",
      of: this,
      offset: "-15 0"
    });
  });
};
```

I'm still a noob with javascript and jQuery so I apologize for any silliness in the code.